# Encriptar dados entre Controller Asp.Net Mvc e Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Faço a comunicação entre `Back` e `Front` `End` com `Ajax`, mas não sei como encriptar os dados transportados, esse é um método do meu `controller` que retorna um `Json` que chamo através do `Ajax`:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/atividades/ListarWmsAtividadeId/{IdWmsAtividade}")]
public IActionResult ListarWmsAtividadeId(int IdWmsAtividade)
{
    var wmsatividade = new wmsatividade();

    wmsatividade = _wmsatividadeRepositorio.ListarId(IdWmsAtividade);

    if (wmsatividade == null)
       return Json(new { validarequisicao = "wmsatividade não encontrado" });

    return Json(wmsatividade);
}
```

Esse é meu método no `front end` para chamada do método

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: stipo,
    url: surl + parametros,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (dados)
    {
        if (dados.hasOwnProperty('validarequisicao'))
        {
            MensagemTextDanger(dados.validarequisicao, scampo);
            retorno = dados
        }
        else
        {
            if (dados != null)
                retorno = dados;                  
        }
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        MensagemTextDanger('Erro requisição ' + sorigem,scampo)
    }
});
```

O código está funcional, porém no console é possível ver o conteúdo dentro do arquivo `Json`, e preciso encriptar esses dados.

Comment: Não entendi porque é o comportamento normal.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, eu sou bem iniciante na tecnologia, então talvez a dúvida seja sem sentido. Mas quando eu faço um select trazendo uma classe preenchida como a da pergunta, o usuário se tiver um pouco de conhecimento, poderá inspecionar e ver os dados do retorno do select, está correto dessa forma mesmo?

Comment: Quando é feito assim, você tem a possibilidade de verificar o retorno e pelo console do navegador é trazido essas informações. é um comportamento normal, é assim mesmo, agora fator segurança, criptografia etc... é outro assunto. Tome cuidado em não retornar dados sensiveis como por exemplo senhas de usuários (isso nunca), agora dados que vão aparecer na tela do usuário não tem problema se não forem como eu disse sensiveis

Comment: Entendi, perfeito no caso de fato não há problemas, mas está claro que dados sensíveis devem ser escondidos.. eu venho de aplicações desktop(Delphi) pra mim alguns conceitos ainda são bem diferentes e nublados, obrigado pela ajuda @VirgilioNovic